# Determine all matrices $M\in M_3(\mathbb K)$ such that $M^2 = O_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How to determine all matrices $M\in M_3(\mathbb K)$ such that $M^2=O_3$?

I tried saying that if

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d& e & h\\
i & j & k\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

then$$M^2=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d& e & h\\
i & j & k\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d& e & h\\
i & j & k\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

therefore:

\begin{cases}
a^2 +bd + gc =0\\
ab+be + ch =0\\
ac + bf + ci=0\\
...
\end{cases}

but it seems to be the wrong way.

The answer given which I don't understand was:

Let suppose that $M\neq O_3$ and let be $\phi$ the associated endomorphism canonically associated to $M$.

Then it exists a vector $\vec x$ such that $\phi (x) =0$.

We have $Im\phi\subset \ker \phi$ (but I don't understand why).

and because $\dim Im \phi+\dim\ker\phi=3$ then necessarily $\dim Im \phi=1$ and $\dim\ker\phi=3$ (Which I think is wrong).

Because $\phi(x)\in\ker\phi$ (I still don't understand why), $z\in\ker\phi$ exists such that {\phi (x),x} be a basis of $\ker\phi$.

The family $F=\{x,\phi x,z\}$ is free and the matrix $\phi$ regarding this basis is:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say that $M^2 = 0$, you're saying that 
$$
M(Mx) = 0
$$
for every $x \in  \Bbb{R}^3$.

Since the set of all $Mx$ (as $x$ ranges over $ \Bbb{R}^3$) is exactly the image of $\phi$, and $M$ times each of these is zero, each of them (i.e., each item in the image of $\phi$) must be in the kernel of $\phi$.

The thing you think is wrong is, in fact, wrong: they should have written dim ker $\phi \ge 1$ and dim im $\phi \le 2$.

Let's walk through that proof step by step, with a few extra details.

> Let suppose that $M\neq O_3$ and let be $\phi$ the associated
>   endomorphism canonically associated to $M$.

There are two possibilities: $M = 0$ and $M \ne 0$. The first one is easy, so let's look at the second, and let's define $\phi:  \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3 : x \mapsto Mx$.

> Then there exists a vector $\vec x$ such that $\phi (x) =0$.

Because $M^2 = 0$, we know that $M(Mx) = 0$ for every $x$. Pick a nonzero $x$. Then either (1) $Mx = 0$, or (2) $y = Mx$ is a nonzero vector. But then since $M(Mx) = My = 0$, $y$ is a nonzero vector in the kernel of $\phi$. So in both cases, $\phi$ has a nonzero element in its kernel. So dim ker $\phi \ge 1$.

> We have $Im\phi\subset \ker \phi$ (but I don't understand why).

Because $Im \phi$ consists of all vectors $Mx$ where $x \in R^3$, and for all vectors $x$, we have $M(Mx) = 0,$ we see that for any vector $y = Mx \in Im \phi$, we have $\phi(y) = My = MMx = 0$, so that $y \in Ker \phi$.

> and because $\dim Im \phi+\dim\ker\phi=3$ then necessarily $\dim Im \phi=1$ and $\dim\ker\phi=3$ (Which I think is wrong).

This is wrong. We only have $\dim Im \phi \ge 1$ and $\dim Ker \phi \le 2$. But suppose that $\dim Im \phi = 2$. Then $\dim Ker \phi = 1$. But since $Im \phi \subset ker \phi$, this is impossible (by dimension). So we must have $\dim Im \phi = 1$ and $\dim ker \phi = 2$.

> Because $\phi(x)\in\ker\phi$ (I still don't understand why), $z\in\ker\phi$ exists such that {\phi (x),x} be a basis of $\ker\phi$.

Frankly, the statement above makes no sense to me: the conclusion seems to be unrelated to $z$. But the idea is, I think, this:

- If you start with a nonzero vector $x$ with $\phi(x) \ne 0$, then there's some other vector $z \in Ker \phi$ with the property that $\phi(x), z$ is a basis of the kernel. Why? Because the kernel is two-dimensional, and any linearly independent set (like the singleton $\{ \phi(x) \}$) can be extended to a basis.
- The triple $x, \phi(x), z$ is a basis of $R^3$ (this takes some proving)
- The matrix of $\phi$ with respect to this basis is the one given in the next line.

> The family $F=\{x,\phi x,z\}$ is free and the matrix $\phi$ regarding
>   this basis is:
>
> \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

So the only question that remains is "can you prove that those three vectors form a basis of 3-space?"

**Addendum after comments**

We have $x, \phi(x), z$, where $x$ and $\phi(x)$ are nonzero, and $z$ is an element of $ker \phi$ that's independent of $\phi(x)$. We'd like to show that these three form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Since the dimension is three, it suffices to show that they're linearly independent. So suppose that
$$
\alpha x + \beta \phi(x) + \gamma z = 0.
$$
We must show that the coefficients (in greek letters) are all zero. Apply the transformation $\phi$ (which satisfies $\phi(\phi u) = 0$ for all $u$) to the statement above to get
\begin{align}
\phi(\alpha x + \beta \phi(x) + \gamma z) &  = \phi(0) \\
\phi(\alpha x) + \phi(\beta \phi(x)) + \phi(\gamma z)) &  = 0 \\
\alpha \phi(x) + \beta \phi(\phi(x)) + \gamma \phi(z)) &  = 0 \\
\alpha \phi(x) + \beta 0 + \gamma 0 &  = 0 \\
\end{align}
where the first three steps follow from linearity of $\phi$, and the last because $\phi^2 = 0$ and because $z \in ker ~\phi$. From this, we conclude $\alpha = 0$.

Now we have $\beta \phi(x) + \gamma z = 0$. But $\phi(x)$ and $z$ were chosen to be a basis of $ker~ \phi$, hence are linearly independent. So $\beta = \gamma = 0$ and we're done. The three vectors really do form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

What about the matrix of $\phi$ in this basis? Let's look at $\phi(u)$ for $u = x$ and write it in terms of the basis $x, \phi(x), z$, and then do the same for $u = \phi(x)$ and for $u = z$. Well: 
$$
\phi(x) = 0 x + 1 \phi(x) + 0 z
$$
so the first column of the matrix contains the coefficients $0,1,0$, and is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What about $u = \phi(x)$. Well, in this case, $\phi(u) = \phi(\phi(x)) = 0$, so we have
$$
\phi(\phi(x)) = 0 x + 0 \phi(x) + 0z.
$$
So the second column is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
And finally, for $u = z$, we know that $z \in ker~\phi$, so $\phi z = 0$. Thus the third column is also 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
and the matrix (in the $x, \phi(x), z$ basis) overall is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1& 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Nice answer. However, I would'nt say it is wrong (in the part using $\text{dim Im}+\text{dim Ker}=3$). It is not wrong, it is abusively elusive, IMHO. Or maybe I am missing something? EDIT: I didn't see it said $\text{dim Ker }\phi=3$. Mea culpa

Comment: @John  Hughes, Thank you for this really pedagogical and step by step answer! Yet, why does *The matrix of ϕ with respect to this basis is the one given in the next line. * gives the matrix \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}? I can't prove that those vectors form the basis of a 3-space as far as the two last seems to be dependant?

Comment: See my "post-comment additions" for answers to both these questions.

Comment: Another surprisingly nice approach is via the SVD.

Comment: Agreed...I thought about that while driving today. But I doubt that OP has seen the SVD, which tends to get covered long after material like this. Then again, an answer that "points forward" can be a Good Thing, too.

Comment: @JohnHughes, Yes, haven't seen it yet..!

Answer (score 3):

$M=O_{3}$ is obviously such a matrix. Let suppose $M\neq O_{3}$ and let $\phi$ be the morphism canonically associated to $M$.

As $M^{2}=O_{3}$, it means that whatever $x\in\mathbb{K}^{3}$, we have $\phi(\phi(x))=0$, hence $\phi(x)\in\text{ Ker }\phi$ for any $x\in\mathbb{K^{3}}$, which explicitly means that $\text{ Im }\phi\subset\text{ Ker }\phi$ since $\text{ Im }\phi :=\{\phi(x)\mid x\in\mathbb{K^{3}}\}$.

As $M\neq O_{3}$, there exists at least one $x\in\mathbb{K}^{3}$ such that $\phi(x)\neq 0$, i.e. $\text{ Im }\phi\neq\{0\}$, so that $\text{ dim }\text{ Im }\phi$ is at least $1$. Since we also have

$$\text{ dim }\text{ Im }\phi + \text{ dim }\text{ Ker }\phi = \text{ dim }\mathbb{K^{3}}=3$$

and because $1\le \text{ dim }\text{ Im }\phi\le \text{ dim }\text{ Ker }\phi$, the only possibility is $\text{ dim }\text{ Im }\phi=1$ and $\text{ dim }\text{ Ker }\phi=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine, and it has its advantages, but it's perhaps computationally unpleasant.

Since $0 = \phi^2 = \phi \circ \phi$, for all $x \in \Bbb K^3$ we have $\phi(\phi(x)) = 0$, so $\phi(\operatorname{im} \phi) = 0$, or equivalently, $$\operatorname{im} \phi \subseteq \ker \phi$$ as claimed, and in particular we have
$$\dim \operatorname{im} \phi \leq \dim \ker \phi.$$ By the Rank-Nullity Theorem we have
$$\dim \operatorname{im} \phi + \dim \ker \phi = 3 ,$$ so $\dim \operatorname{im} \phi \leq 1$. On the other hand, since $\phi \neq 0$, we must have $\dim \operatorname{im} \phi > 0$, so $\dim \operatorname{im} \phi = 1 .$

---

Here's an alternative method for addressing the problem, which in particular uses the Jordan Canonical Form: Notice that if $M^2 = 0$ and $P$ is invertible, then $(P M P^{-1})^2 = 0$, that is the property is invariant under similarity. On the other hand, $M^2 = 0$ implies that all of the eigenvalues of $M$ are zero, and the only Jordan blocks that square to $0$ are $0$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. So, up to similarity the only matrices with square the zero matrix are the zero matrix itself and $$J := \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} .$$ (It's not hard to build a permutation matrix that conjugates $J$ to the matrix of the form in the question.)

So, all nonzero $3 \times 3$ matrices with square zero can be written as
$$P^{-1} J P$$ for some invertible $P$.

Comment: Since the work needed to do this exercise is essentially the same work you do to *prove* the Jordan form exists, I suspect that this exercise appears well before the Jordan form in this person's reading of linear algebra...but that's just a guess.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, I basically agree: I prefaced the discussion of the Jordan form with "Alternatively" for that reason, with an audience of people who know about the Jordan form in mind; like you say, this possibly does not include OP. Anyway, I've added a horizontal rule and tweaked the wording to emphasize that this discussion/approach really is logically separate from the first part of my answer, which addresses the specific issue that OP said they didn't understand (the indicated containment and the rank of the transformation $\phi$).